# How to export mysql database through command line, but ignore some specific table

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04

I have a large MySQL database its almost 434 tables. I would like the export the database but ignore or skip a couple of tables. This process should be done through command line, because i have more than 6 GB+ data in database. What is the proper syntax to export all tables, but ignore some specific of them?

```
mysqldump -u root -p database directory table1 table2 table2 > /var/www/mydb_tables.sql
```

This query is working fine, but its difficulty to mention all the 434+ table name. I want the query that skip only specific table and export remaining all table through command line.

Comment: this may help http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9306/how-do-you-mysqldump-specific-tables

Comment: Reference dba.stackexchange: [dump everything except t1, t2, and t3, do this][1]


  [1]: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9306/how-do-you-mysqldump-specific-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [--ignore-table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table) to skip certain tables.

```
 mysqldump -u username -p database --ignore-table=database.table1 --ignore-table=database.table2 > /var/www/mydb_tables.sql
```